# Need to "Change Owner Trust" on PGP key in Kleopatra

Tags: pgp, truststore, secret-key

I have an ETL that is Un-PGPing a file sent to us. This process works for two people on our team but fails for the rest on the unPGP step. We all use Kleopatra for our key encryption/decryption and have the same key's imported.

I have noticed that the keys on the systems that work are set to the trust level "This is my certificate" (sometimes called Ultimate trust). However the option to set to that level on the other systems are grayed out.

I have tried to change the level via a CMD prompt based on this article:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129474/how-to-raise-a-key-to-ultimate-trust-on-another-machine

However I do not get the same prompts as described.

When debuging with CMD /K I see:
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

[UNPGP Failure Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJct8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to change my trust,

```
gpg --edit-key [key-id]  
trust   
5
```

though this didn't end up solving my problems.

I discovered when I typed `gpg --list-secret-keys`  I would get nothing in return despite having kleopatra tell me the keys were properly installed.

I found and staged the secret key's I needed then imported them using GPG.

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import "filename.asc"
```

This fixed my issue!